# ADT bundle detecting wrong version of ADT installed

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just downloaded and installed the ADT bundle from July 2nd (adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip) on Xubuntu 14.04.  I previously had been using the version from . . . February or so.  It's an older version . . . 23.0.2 .  Anyway, I unzipped the new ADT bundle into a separate directory, but in the same subdirectory as my previous ADT bundle install.  Big mistake.

The new bundle's Eclipse IDE started using the sdk directory from the old bundle.  So, I moved the old bundle into a different location, and when Eclipse started complaining it couldn't find the SDK directory, I pointed it to the proper one.  It worked, but now Eclipse is reporting the ADT bundle version to be 23.0.2 instead of 32.0.1 (or whatever the July 2nd release version is).  This is causing havoc with the software updater and installer.  It wants to install versions of Traceview (for example) intended for 23.0.2 rather than the latest software.  I thought it might have something to do with environment variables, but I can find no environment variable related to the SDK version.

Any thoughts?

edit: Woops, 23.0.2 IS the latest version.  Not sure where I got 32.0.1.  Guess it's working as intended, then.

edit edit: I have punted on the ADT bundle and have switched to Android Studio.  Setting Gradle up for offline build was a headache, but now that it's working, it's rather nice.

Comment: use android studio instead, its a much better ide.

Comment: Maybe someday I will, but I'd like to sort out this problem nevertheless.  Android Studio is still in beta anyway, is it not?

Comment: even when it was in developer preview it was better than what eclipse has to offer.

Comment: Okay, that's great.  Maybe I'll check it out.  But I still want to know why Eclipse is reporting my ADT Bundle to be 23.0.2 when it's really 32.0.1 or 32.0.2.  The Android SDK manager has no problem properly detecting what SDK elements are installed, everything works, I just can't install the proper stuff from the Eclipse repositories like StackTrace because Eclipse is convinced I'm still on 23.0.2.  So sad.

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a rough ride.  I just spent all afternoon recovering from the exact same situation (in my case, surprisingly, I got by referencing the stale sdk for over a month without noticing it; but then I deleted the folder because it was taking up space :\ - big mistake).

The first step you'll want to take: Eclipse > Preferences > Android - and change the sdk location to the correct folder path (ending .../sdk/).

From this point, your existing projects and eclipse are likely still woefully misconfigured, and you'll hit one or more of the issues below.  I don't know how much of the following was actually resolving problems versus waving my hands around frantically, but it did all work in the end:

A) [Eclipse - Mac Os Default JRE missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736993/eclipse-mac-os-default-jre-missing) (accepted answer)

B) [Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757406/cannot-find-the-class-file-for-java-lang-object) (accepted answer)

C) [Eclipse "Invalid Project Description" when creating new project from existing source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784652/eclipse-invalid-project-description-when-creating-new-project-from-existing-so) (Rubenulis' answer; I had to remove each project in my workspace, and re-add it via his method #1)

D) and then for each project I had to right click > Properties > Android (far left), and select the new android sdk, click ok (not apply for whatever reason); and then reopen properties again to do properties > build path > add library > Android Classpath Container).  If you ran into my trouble with the JRE going missing, you'd ALSO need to add library > JRE System Library (making sure that Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs is not an empty list first).  If the build path lists anything saying "system library missing" you need to remove that and keep futzing around, trying to re-add whatever it was supposed to be.

Good luck.

Comment: Just an update, but I have mostly switched to Android Studio now that I've sorted out all the offline build problems with Gradle (ugh).  Overall, I am happier using Android Studio.  Now I'm just using Eclipse Luna for standard Java work, and Studio for Android stuff.  It's a shame that you had to go through all that trouble to resolve your problem, and I am not surprised that Google is punting on the ADT Bundle.