# Error:The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My adt work one time very well and i am able to run all the projects and then  open in next day it wants some updates for sdk otherwise show error of DDMS missing i updated the sdk and now
Error: **Resource   Path Location Type The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project**
Do any one tell me how to solve all these errors and work on ADT smoothly or there any other option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9341736/1160282 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752392/1160282 may be you missing JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your IDE couln't recognise your SDK location, if you are using MyEclipse the do following

1. Go to Windows -> preference -> Android and set your sdk path again.
2. In Studio File -> setting and then set your sdk path.

Then restart eclipse/studio.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing Java itself within the IDE which include `java.lang.Object`. I'd check to see if the project you are working with has Java on the build path.